# how to add jquery-fileupload plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I have used carrierwave and followed the [link](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V6) 
But not able make it like demo of jquery-fileupload [link](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Can anyone guide me where to place the files of js file and images and how to include javascript in html.

if any tutorial or example of Rails, that will be great...
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Different people have different opinion about where it is OK to keep the files. Generally,

1. Javascript are kept in `js` or `script`
2. Images are kept in `img` or `images` or `media`

Including JS on the HTML is done as this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/jsfile.js'></script>
```